# Как очистить данные в excel файле от дубликатов в Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Начинающий дата аналитик. Нужно очистить данные в python, взятые из xlsx файла. У части строк есть свой дубликат, но с дополнительными данными.

[image: Input]

Также, у дубликатов в есть своя кодировка в первом столбце (x,y,z). Как собрать все данные по строке из дубликатов, убрать эти дубликаты и заменить столбец с кодировкой на новый столбец с перечислением кодировок? С какой стороны заходить сначала и какие технологии можно применить?

Такая таблица должна получится в итоге:

[image: Output]

В электронном виде:

Input

```
    Code       NAME     ID   LON   LAT NAME of place
0      1  Barbarian  00001    57    91              
1      1       Bard           58    92     Soltmarsh
2      1     Cleric  00003                          
3      1        NaN  00004    60    94      Valakkia
4      1     Wizard  00005    61                    
5      1    Warrior  00006    62    96           
6      1      Rogue  00007    63    97              
7      1       Monk  00009    65    99              
8      1        NaN           66   100     Waterdeep
9      2        NaN           57    91     Waterdeep
10     2       Bard  00002    58           Soltmarsh
11     2     Cleric  00003    59             Barovia
12     2       Mage           60    94      Valakkia
13     2     Wizard  00005    61                    
14     2    Warrior                            Abyss
15     2      Rogue  00007    63    97              
16     2        NaN                 99        Laylon
17     2        NaN           66   100     Waterdeep
18     3  Barbarian  00001    57    91              
19     3        NaN  00002    58           Soltmarsh
20     3       Mage  00004    60    94              
21     3     Wizard           61    95              
22     3        NaN  00006    62    96         Abyss
23     3      Rogue  00007    63    97              
24     3      Druid  00008    64    98   Neverwinter
25     3       Monk  00009                          
26     3    Warlock  00010    66   100     Waterdeep `
```

Output

```
        NAME  ID  LON  LAT  NAME of place    Codes
0  Barbarian   1   57   91      Waterdeep  1, 2, 3
1       Bard   2   58   92      Soltmarsh  1, 2, 3
2     Cleric   3   59   93        Barovia     1, 2
3       Mage   4   60   94       Valakkia  1, 2, 3
4     Wizard   5   61   95      Soltmarsh  1, 2, 3
5    Warrior   6   62   96          Abyss  1, 2, 3
6      Rogue   7   63   97  Baldur's Gate  1, 2, 3
7      Druid   8   64   98    Neverwinter        3
8       Monk   9   65   99         Laylon  1, 2, 3
9    Warlock  10   66  100      Waterdeep  1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Нужно описать правило по которому соединяются строки. Почему не может быть A3 B3 C1?

Comment: Исправил скрин - индексы должны совпадать.

Comment: 1. Давайте пока не будем говорить об excel, а разберемся с датафреймом pandas. 2. Нужно привести пример данных в электронном виде. 3. Из вашего вопроса не понятно - дубликаты оцениваются только по первой колонке (A)?

Comment: 2) Добавил пример данных  3) По всем колонкам, кроме Code и Name of Place - они не индивидуальные.